# Change the default datasource in spring batch

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I want to use mysql database in spring batch application. Where should I keep my XML file with the details of datasource.
currently i have kept the `env-context.xml` in `src/main/resources/META-INF/batch/override/manager`

Content of `env-context.xml`:

```
<!-- connect to database -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo_db" />
    <property name="username" value="testuser" />
    <property name="password" value="12345" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Please note that the tag [tag:batch-file] is for questions about windows batch-files, which are interpreted by cmd and contain windows command, and not about spring batch. For more info on different tags, I suggest looking at the [info tab](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info) of that tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common approach is to put this kind of configuration parameters into a properties file in order to externalize them as they will change from one environment to another.

It can be done as next:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:datasource.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${datasource.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${datasource.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${datasource.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${datasource.password}" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Then you put your file `datasource.properties` into the classpath, this file will have a content of type:

```
datasource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo_db
datasource.username=testuser
datasource.password=12345
```